# How to create a Eye rig with cornea deformation

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm trying to create a realistic Eye rig that uses bones instead of shapekeys to achieve more realistic results. I want the eyelids to deform around the cornea when the eye is moved around.

And while I have the eyelid being entirelly moved by bones I can't make it wrap around the eye because of the cornea. As you can see in the picture below the eyelid is clipping trough the eye mesh.

[image]

The eye was made with anatomic references and thus it's accurate, as such it has the "bulge" of the cornea.

Video showing what I want to achieve: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAZIvyAJfeM

Is it possible to achieve this in Blender?

Comment: Here is a correctly rigged test character created with Makehuman:[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6128" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6128/)

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly this is suppose to help me. It has a setup very identical to mine except that the eye here is clearly lacking a cornea which makes it incorrect. And thus there is no clipping.

Comment: you can copy the weights and the bone position

Comment: That would do nothing. I'm going to update my question with a video of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Updated question with video of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried with the *Warp* modifier but it seems hard to make it work with a complexe topology, a *Lattice* modifier seems much more convenient:

- First remove all the *Copy Transforms* constraints of your 3 bones (not sure why you want those).
- In *Pose* mode, close the eyelid a bit so that you'll be able to test the modifier when the eyes are closed.
- Create a lattice in front of your eye: <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Lattice*. Scale it down.
- Subdivide it a bit, for example U and W values > 7, and make it flat on the Y axis with a V value of 1.
- Give your eyelid mesh a *Lattice* modifier. Choose the lattice as *Object*.
- Select your lattice, go in *Edit* mode, select the central vertices and make it a bit round, use the *Proportional Editing / Sphere falloff type* to help you.
- Parent the lattice to the eye bone: <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Bone*.
- Now when you'll move the bone, the transformation of the eyelid will follow.
- If necessary make some adjustments to the lattice in *Edit* mode, or scale it up or down in *Object* mode, play with the modifier *Strength* (and create keyframes if the influence changes through time). You can also limit the lattice influence on only a part of the eyelid mesh (with a vertex group that you'll set in the *Vertex Group* field of the modifier), etc...

[image]

Comment: Sadly, I'm not getting good results. The mesh is just being pushed away leaving gaps between the eye and the eyelids.

Comment: You need to play subtly with parameters, and also the position of the empties count, so maybe parent each of them to their own bone so that you can play on their position, there is no reason you could not make it work the way you want.

Comment: I'll experiment some more with them. But it seems that it is much harder to achieve this without shapekeys.

Comment: Yea, this really doesn't work. I tried all the values and moving things around but nothing seems to change.

Comment: could you please share this part of your file so that I can try, because I don't see how it can't work as you can set whatever factor you want: radius, strength, shape of the bump, etc...

Comment: Here is the blend file with just one of the eye sockets with the Warp setup:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/n1eg2gj4de5llgy/Eye_warp.blend?dl=0

Comment: I don't really understand some things in your setup but anyway, it looks like it's hard to make Warp work fine with a complex shape like this one, so I'm going to dig into the problem or try to find something else

Comment: What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: Ok so a Lattice may be preferable and seems to work fine, I'll try to edit my answer tomorrow  ;)

Comment: Okay. I'll patiently wait for the answer. :)

Comment: edited, I think it's much simpler with Lattice

Comment: Thank you!! This works great! I never used a lattice before, I never had a reason to use or so I thought.
Tell me, can a lattice have any shape?

Comment: No it can't have any shape, you can just choose the amont of edges loops, with the Mesh modifier you can use any sort of mesh but I don't think it can be useful for your current goal

Comment: Ah alright. Thanks for the help though!